# how to input multiple rows in codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i have problem with my program. exemple we input sum collie is 3. it will show 3 table input. table input is long, wide, lenght, weight. so how to input to database with multiple row?

code in view

```
<div style="min-height:370px;">
        <form method="post" name="hit">
            <?php 
                if (isset($_POST['jmlbrg'])){
                $jmlcollie = $_POST['jmlcollie'];

             ?>
            <div>
                <?php
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $jmlcollie; $i++) {
                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="text" class="span1 text-center" name="<?php echo 'jml'.$i;?>" id="<?php echo 'jml'.$i;?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="span3 text-center" name="<?php echo 'jenisbrg'.$i;?>" id="<?php echo 'jenisbrg'.$i;?>">
                    <input type="text" class="span2 text-center" name="<?php echo 'long'.$i; ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="span2 text-center" name="<?php echo 'wide'.$i; ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="span2 text-center" name="<?php echo 'length'.$i; ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="span3 text-center" name="<?php echo 'weight'.$i; ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="span3 text-center" name="<?php echo 'volume'.$i; ?>" id="<?php echo 'volume'.$i; ?>">
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </form>

    </div>
```

code in modal

```
function add(){

    $data = array(
        'no_btb' => $this->input->post('nobtb'),
        'jenis_brg' => $this->input->post('<?php echo 'jenisbrg),
        'long' => $this->input->post('<?php echo 'long'.$i; ?>'),
        'wide' => $this->input->post('<?php echo 'wide'.$i; ?>'),
        'length' => $this->input->post('<?php echo 'length'.$i; ?>'),
        'weight' => $this->input->post('<?php echo 'weight'.$i; ?>'),
        'volume' => $this->input->post('<?php echo 'volume'.$i; ?>'),
    );
    $this->db->insert('detail_barang', $data);

    $data = array(
        'no_btb' => $this->input->post('nobtb'),
        'jml_collie' => $this->input->post('jmlcollie'),
        'total_volume' => $this->input->post('tot_volume'),
    );
    $this->db->insert('btb', $data);

}
```

i hope any solution with my problem. thank before !

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Don't use `POST`, `GET`, `SESSION` in model. Do all the logics and data preparation in controller itself. Just do only DB Activities in Model.

For your question, store `$jmlcollie` in a hidden variable in View.

```
<input type='hidden' name='jmlcollie' value='<?php echo $jmlcollie;?>'/>
```

In cotroller, do loop with `$this->input->post("jmlcollie");`

Prepare the data in Controller:

```
$detail_barang= array();
$jmlcollie = $this->input->post("jmlcollie");
for ($i=1; $i <= $jmlcollie; $i++) {
$detail_barang[] = array(
        'no_btb' => $this->input->post('nobtb'),
        'jenis_brg' => $this->input->post('jenisbrg'),
        'long' => $this->input->post('long'.$i),
        'wide' => $this->input->post('wide'.$i),
        'length' => $this->input->post('length'.$i),
        'weight' => $this->input->post('weight'.$i),
        'volume' => $this->input->post('volume'.$i),
    );
}
 $btb = array(
        'no_btb' => $this->input->post('nobtb'),
        'jml_collie' => $this->input->post('jmlcollie'),
        'total_volume' => $this->input->post('tot_volume'),
    );
```

Now call your model funcions:

```
$this->MODEL_NAME->add($detail_barang,$btb);
```

In you model

```
function add($detail_barang,$btb){

   foreach($detail_barang as $data) // you cna do batch insert also.
   {
       $this->db->insert('detail_barang', $data);
   }
   $this->db->insert('btb', $btb);

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but when i try is not working. any error in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'jenisbrg' (T_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\warehouse\application\controllers\btb.php

Comment: check now. I missed a single quote in my answer.

Comment: okay i has been find it. and now any error in modal. error is show Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Filename: models/m_btb.php

Comment: Are you calling add() with correct model name in controller? Do some debugging in your code. Do print_r($detail_barang) in add() function. Then you can find the problem.

Comment: yes of course i call like this, $this->m_btb->add($detail_barang,$btb); and when i print_r($detail_barang) the output is Array ( [0] => Array ( [no_btb] => 5465 [jenis_brg] => [long] => [wide] => [length] => [weight] => [volume] => ) )

Comment: this is controller code http://pastebin.com/XGjvc6pi and this is code in model http://pastebin.com/QQ5dsbue and the last code view http://pastebin.com/QBcn44JP

Comment: i has been check but i dont know where is the problem. may be you can help me check my code. thank you

Comment: Problem in your view file. You are assign value to $jmlcollie from POST. But you have set hidden value before the assignment. change hidden field place to  after the assignment of $jmlcollie. Then problem solved.